# winapi - DeferWindowPos and InvalidateRect

Tags: winapi

I have a main window which allows to display a child modal dialog. That dialog window is created based on the resource file using DialogBox function. It contains a few controls and a horizontal splitter which are repositioned/resized when handling WM_SIZE and WM_MOUSEMOVE messages. I use BeginDeferWindowPos, DeferWindowPos and EndDeferWindowPos functions. It looks like that everything is repainted correctly. Should I also call InvalidateRect after EndDeferWindowPos ? Is there any scenario where it may be necessary ? I don't handle WM_PAINT message.

Comment: There is no such thing as a *"child modal dialog"*. It's either a child window, or an (owned) modal dialog. Terminology is important. [Window Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features) explains common terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-deferwindowpos) for the `DeferWindowPos` function would strongly suggest that, so long as you don't have the `SWP_NOREDRAW` bit set in the `uFlags` argument, you do *not* need to call `InvalidateRect` after you have called `EndDeferWindowPos`:

> SWP_NOREDRAW 0x0008
>  Does not redraw changes. If this flag is set,
>   no repainting of any kind occurs. This applies to the client area, the
>   nonclient area (including the title bar and scroll bars), and any part
>   of the parent window uncovered as a result of the window being moved.
>   When this flag is set, the application must explicitly invalidate or
>   redraw any parts of the window and parent window that need redrawing.